# jquery image scroller starts out white

Tags: jquery, image, background, fadein

Im having trouble with a jquery css3 background image scroller on my test site. It works fine, except I cant figure out why it shows a blank white screen for the first couple seconds before switching between images. I want it to just start up showing an image and then scroll through the rest of the images, rather than start out white and scroll through the images.

HTML

```
<div id="imgscroll">
<img src="images/bg/bg_1.jpg" />
<img src="images/bg/bg_2.jpg" />
<img src="images/bg/bg_3.jpg" />
<img src="images/bg/bg_4.jpg" />
<img src="images/bg/bg_5.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imgscroll {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
#imgscroll img {
position:absolute;
top:0;
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
z-index: -3;
}
```

JS

```
$('img').hide();
function test() {
$("#imgscroll img").first().fadeIn(2500);
$("#imgscroll img").first().appendTo('#imgscroll').fadeOut(2500);
setTimeout(test, 5000);
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be because you have it fading in and out for 2.5 seconds each:

```
$("#imgscroll img").first().fadeIn(2500);
$("#imgscroll img").first().appendTo('#imgscroll').fadeOut(2500);
```

Try removing those 2 lines ^

Comment: I removed those two and then nothing happens at all

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to like 50 instead pf 2500

Comment: nope, didnt work either, just makes the fade effect much quicker

Comment: Oh okay, which slider are you using?